# Remove extra space in virtual display

Tags: 14.04, display, xfce, xrandr

I am using two monitors and when moving the mouse from one to the other it disappears somewhere in the middle for a while. There is some virtual space between both monitors.

I am using xfce.

`xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5760 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1920x1080+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.0     60.0  
   1024x576       60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     59.9  
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.0     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     59.9
```

I am sure the problem is that 3840 in DVI-I-1, I just cannot figure out how to remove it. Also, there is no `xorg.conf` file in my machine apparently, only `xorg.conf.failsafe`.

Answer (score 0):

I used `arandr` to get the right `xrandr` configuration in the form of a shell script and set it up to run at session startup to make the change permanent.

Unfortunately, even though running the script fixed the issue, it would not be automatically done at the beginning of a session, so I have just upgraded to xfce 4.12, which has better support for multiple displays and this has taken care of the issue.